# What does IOException mean on a javamail IMAPS connection?

Tags: imap, jakarta-mail, websphere-7, exchange-server

I'm trying to connect to an exchange server with IMAPS on port 443 (it's been configured this way on the other end) using the following code:
.
.
.

```
            props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_30/jre/lib/security/cacerts");
            props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
            props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "jks");
            props.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");

            System.setProperties(props);

            props = System.getProperties();

            final Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            session.setDebug(debug);
            com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder inbox = null;
            Store store = null;

            store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect(host, 443, username, password);
            inbox = (com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("INBOX");
```

.
.
.

Judging from the fact that I get no certificate errors, they are correctly loaded from the store location. However, I get the following trace once the code reaches the connect statement:"

```
[29/01/13 18:23:02:811 CST] 0000007d SystemOut     O DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
[29/01/13 18:23:02:812 CST] 0000007d SystemOut     O DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384

[29/01/13 18:18:42:814 CST] 0000007d SystemErr     R javax.mail.MessagingException;
nested exception is:
java.io.IOException
[29/01/13 18:18:42:814 CST] 0000007d SystemErr     R    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:479)
[29/01/13 18:18:42:814 CST] 0000007d SystemErr     R    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
[29/01/13 18:18:42:814 CST] 0000007d SystemErr     R    at com.scots.utils.MailPoller$1.run(MailPoller.java:74)
[29/01/13 18:18:42:815 CST] 0000007d SystemErr     R    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:738)
[29/01/13 18:18:42:815 CST] 0000007d SystemErr     R Caused by: java.io.IOException
[29/01/13 18:18:42:815 CST] 0000007d SystemErr     R    at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.read0(ResponseInputStream.java:99)
[29/01/13 18:18:42:815 CST] 0000007d SystemErr     R    at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.readResponse(ResponseInputStream.java:67)
[29/01/13 18:18:42:815 CST] 0000007d SystemErr     R    at com.sun.mail.iap.Response.<init>(Response.java:83)
[29/01/13 18:18:42:815 CST] 0000007d SystemErr     R    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.<init>(IMAPResponse.java:48)
[29/01/13 18:18:42:815 CST] 0000007d SystemErr     R    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.readResponse(IMAPResponse.java:122)
[29/01/13 18:18:42:815 CST] 0000007d SystemErr     R    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:230)
[29/01/13 18:18:42:815 CST] 0000007d SystemErr     R    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:91)
[29/01/13 18:18:42:815 CST] 0000007d SystemErr     R    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:87)
[29/01/13 18:18:42:815 CST] 0000007d SystemErr     R    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:446)
[29/01/13 18:18:42:816 CST] 0000007d SystemErr     R    ... 3 more
```

And nothing else! I've searched everywhere for the possible meanings or causes for an IOException thrown during the connect execution, but I've got nothing so far.

Given that the stacktrace doesn't go any further and the only line of my own code referenced in it is the connect statement itself (com.scots.utils.MailPoller$1.run(MailPoller.java:74), I really don't have much to go on.

The only thing that comes to mind that could be causing throuble is that I've put the mail polling mechanics inside another thread (a run method). Could that be causing trouble?

Any ideas you could provide will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much information in the exceptions, but I think the underlying cause is most likely that you really aren't handling the SSL connection properly.  The JavaMail [SSLNOTES.txt](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail145sslnotes-1562622.html) file has some debugging tips and pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What do you think I'm not handling correctly regarding SSL? I set the necessary certificates into my keystore but didn't do much else, trusting that invoking the imaps session would take care of the connection. The only thing that stands out from the SSLNOTES file is that it mentions setting the host and port as properties instead of passing them to the connect method. Would this make a difference?

Comment: No.  I don't know what's wrong, I would just be guessing, that's why I'm suggesting getting more data from the debugging output.  See the Debugging section of SSLNOTES.

Comment: Why is so much information missing from the exceptions, Bill? Is there perhaps a missing SSLException that should have been provided as a cause? And why isn't there any message in the IOException? Can this be fixed please?

Comment: From the stack trace it looks like you're using quite an old version of JavaMail.  That old version throws IOException with no message with it gets a -1 when reading from the socket, which generally indicates that the server has dropped the connection.  Try upgrading to a more recent version to get a better error message, although I don't think that will actually fix your problem.

Comment: It should really have thrown EOFException in that circumstance.

Comment: Well, following Bill's suggestions I redownloaded the javamail 1.4.5 jar as well as turning on both debugging options listed in the SSLNOTES file. After all that, I got the same results and no additional info. I also tried to pass the host and port, as well as the protocol to use as properties for the session instead of parameters in method invokations but didn't get a different result. Given that I need a VPN to reach the mail server and that I get a destination unreachable exception if the VPN is down, I assume I AM reaching something but get the exception while processing the response.

Comment: TLS is also disabled on the target server (I get a no login methods supported error if I enable TLS).

Comment: Wait, you're connecting to the target server with a plain text connection and then getting an error about no login methods supported?  What's the debug output show when that happens?  You're "enabling TLS" by setting the mail.imap.starttls.enable property, right?  What's the debug output show when you do that?

Comment: Yeah, I set the tls property like so: `props.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");` I use the imap protocol instead of imaps (and hence use port 143 instead of the 443 I was instructed to use for SSL) and get a no  login methods supported. I am currently unable to post the exact stack trace but I'll do so come tuesday. Is this error significant to the my situation by chance?

Comment: Something's going wrong.  It's normal to get "no login methods supported" if you connect to a site that wants you to use TLS but you don't issue the STARTTLS command before trying to login.  Perhaps the site you're connecting to isn't properly advertising that TLS is supported.  We need to see the protocol trace to know what's really going on.

Comment: Ok after several days of worrying over configuration it seems that Bill was right. Something was actually wrong on the other end because despite trying to connect to the server over stand alone clients like outlook and thunderbird I received no valid response from the server. They finally got back to me and said that there was something wrong in there -they didn't specify what though- and that they'll let me know when the server is useable again. Thanks to Bill for prodding me into checking with the server admins, even when the actual stack trace was less than useful.